# How do I make after() call a function faster than 1ms without hanging other processes - Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, callback

I'm working on a project where I'm using multiple processes and need my GUI to read inputs faster than 1ms.

Read Bus Process --------> Message Processing Process ------------------>  GUI

```
              send msg   (5 different processes)   send processed msg 
             (every 2ms)                           (read faster than 1ms)
```

The Read Bus Process reads messages from a bus every 2ms and sends the message via a pipe to a specific Message Processing Process (there are 5 different ones) based on an attribute of the read-in message. Once the Message Processing Process has finished its computations on its message, it sends the computed message via a pipe to a GUI which then displays the content in a textbox. Note, I can't increase my read process period (not more than 2ms) because there are many messages on the bus and I can't afford to miss them.

The GUI continuously checks for messages from each of the 5 Message Processing Processes while updating a textbox with the latest message contents. I've tried `after(1, read_function)` but it is not fast enough. I know that it's too slow because once I close the program, there are many messages still left in the pipe that connects each of the Message Processing Processes to the GUI.

I've also tried `after(0, read_function)` but this completely hangs the entire program and I can't click on any buttons on the GUI interface.

Is there any way I can have after() make a callback faster than 1ms without hanging the entire program?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can have after() make a callback faster than 1ms without hanging the entire program?

No, 1ms is the smallest unit of time that `after` can process.

Instead, you could have your `read_function` do multiple reads at each 1ms timeslice.

It's important to know that `after` doesn't guarantee that code will run in the given amount of time. It only guarantees it won't be called before the given amount of time.